# Typescript error when using 'keyof extends' function annotation

Tags: typescript

Still new to aspects of TS' type system. I'm receiving a `'?' expected [1005]` error.

Using TS version 3.1.6

My tsconfig compiler options:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "www/staging/js",
    "rootDir": "src/",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
```

The code causing the issue is the the `handler` parameter type annotation (specifically at the position before the `_convert` method's closing parenthesis):

```
private _convert(
  doc: any, 
  handler: keyof StringHelperService extends (str: string) => string
): any {
  let converted = {} as {[str: string]: any}

  for (let prop in doc) {
    converted[handler(prop)] = doc[prop];
  }
  return converted;
}
```

The annotation is supposed to be saying "a key of StringHelperService, only if it is of the following function signature". Here is StringHelperService:

```
export class StringHelperService {
  public static $inject: ReadonlyArray<string> = [];


  constructor() {
    this.pascalToCamel = this.pascalToCamel.bind(this);
    this.camelToPascal = this.camelToPascal.bind(this);
  }


  pascalToCamel(str: string): string {
    return str.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + str.substring(1);
  }


  camelToPascal(str: string): string {
    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
  }
}
```

#### I've resolved the issue.

Here is the implementor of `_convert` to help explain how the method is used, and how it relates to `StringHelperService`. I created an interface for the function declaration as:

```
export interface StringConverter {
  (str: string): string;
}
```

By using this interface in place of the original annotation for `helper`, I've solved the issue. The issue was that my original annotation was completely wrong. My fallacy was sourced in the misunderstanding that I would use a `key of` type to annotate the type of a member of type T, when indeed it was a METHOD that I wanted. Not sure why I made this leap.

```
export class PropertyNameConverterService {
  public static $inject: ReadonlyArray<string> = ['stringHelper'];


  constructor(private stringHelper: StringHelperService) {
    this._convert = this._convert.bind(this);
    this.pascalToCamel = this.pascalToCamel.bind(this);
    this.camelToPascal = this.camelToPascal.bind(this);
  }


  private _convert(
    doc: any, 
    handler: StringConverter
  ): any {
    let converted = {} as {[str: string]: any}

    for (let prop in doc) {
      converted[handler(prop)] = doc[prop];
    }
    return converted;
  }


  pascalToCamel(doc: any): any {
    return this._convert(doc, this.stringHelper.pascalToCamel);
  }


  camelToPascal(doc: any): any {
    return this._convert(doc, this.stringHelper.camelToPascal);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how you want to use the `_convert` method.

Comment: Yes. I've added the entire class to the OP.

Comment: Ah, that helped me find the issue. Ill update the post. Thanks

Comment: So you expect `handler` to be a *key* but you're treating it like a *function* inside the method.  Not sure what you're doing.  If you really need a key, let us know.

Comment: No; I expected a function, as hinted by the parameter name. I was confused and assumed to use a key annotation. I've updated the post with the correct type annotation.

Answer (score 2):

> The annotation is supposed to be saying "a key of StringHelperService, only if it is of the following function signature".

This does what you say you want the annotation to do.

```
type KeysWithThisSignature<T, U> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P : never;
}[keyof T]

// type Keys = "pascalToCamel" | "camelToPascal"
type Keys = KeysWithThisSignature<StringHelperService, (str: string) => string>;
```

The example you gave, though, is a different use case. In the example, `handler` is not a `string` it is a function with a specific signature.

```
pascalToCamel(doc: any): any {
    // the second argument is a function not a string
    return this._convert(doc, this.stringHelper.pascalToCamel);
}
```

In that case, what you really seem to want for `_convert` is this:

```
private _convert(doc: any, handler: (str: string) => string): any {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I found a solution with an interface, however wasn't completely certain why it worked. This answer explains it perfectly. Thanks.